# Writing to a file using a PeriodicRotatingFileHandler

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, jboss, handler

I'd like to write to files using a handler
I have defined in my standalone.xml (JBoss7)

```
<custom-handler name="HierarchicalPeriodicRotatingFileHandler" class="com.logging.HierarchicalPeriodicRotatingFileHandler"
```

When an event occurs the publish method of that handler is called :

```
public void publish(LogRecord record){
    String name = record.getLoggerName();
    PeriodicRotatingFileHandler appender = map.get(name);
    try {
      if( appender == null) {
          appender = new PeriodicRotatingFileHandler(
                "/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/the-file-name.txt"
                ,true); //append = true
          map.put(name, appender);
      }
      appender.publish(record);
    }
    catch
```

However, no file is created.Even when I create the file , nothing is written

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have the handler attached to a logger?

Comment: Yes !                                                                                                                                            <logger category="com.messaging.connection">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                  <handler name="HierarchicalPeriodicRotatingFileHandler"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>

Comment: That should work then. Can you show by chance show the full class and the config? Specifically what's happening in the `catch` is important.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins well the catch is pretty dumb : catch(Exception e){} , I added 
<module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/> to my module.xml so now the PeriodicRotatingFileHandler is instantiated , however nothing is written to the file

Comment: publish writes to the file, right ?

Comment: Yes publish may write to the file assuming all the checks pass. A couple tips you should probably extend the `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` as this isn't really thread-safe. The catch should definitely handle the message as well.

Comment: any insights on how to properly thread-safe `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler ` ?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just synchronize the method. However that could cause performance issues. You could also use some concurrent Map and the use the `putIfAbsent()` method checking the return value.

Comment: Thanks mate ! I'm jumping on the second option

Answer (score 0):

Ok Leute , here it is.
First , make sure you get your dependancies right in your module.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <!-- Make sure that PeriodicRotatingFileHandler class is loaded properly -->
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/> 
</dependencies>
```

Then, use setFormatter instead of publish to write to a file

```
appender.setFormatter(new Formatter() {
              @Override
              public String format(LogRecord r) {
                    return "The string goes here";
              }
);
```